# Creating typings for inner class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to use typescript in a Salesforce project with [RemoteObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using.htm)

However, I'm not sure how to create typings for the syntax of the external javascript object.

Example of the code use in javascript:

```
var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact({
    FirstName: "Aldo",
    LastName: "Michaels",
    Phone: "(415) 555-1212"
});
```

The part that is tripping me up is `new RemoteObjectModel.Contact()`.  How do I create an interface for this?

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to get to compile

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

declare module RemoteObjectModel {
   export class Account implements IRemoteObject {
       constructor();
       constructor();
       get;
       set;
   }
}

interface IRemoteObject{
    get(field: string): any;
    set(field: string, value: string): any;
}

interface IAppProps{
    remoteObjectModel: RemoteObjectModel
}

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, {}>{
    public state : IAppState;

    constructor(props : IAppProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            accounts: 0
        };
    }

    public render(){
        let account: IRemoteObject = new this.props.remoteObjectModel.Account({
            Name : 'hello!',
            Active : true
        });
        console.log(account);
        return (
            <div>
                New Accounts: {this.state.accounts}
                Account: {account.get('Name')}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//set on the global state
declare var remoteObjectModel : IRemoteObjectModel;

ReactDOM.render(<App remoteObjectModel={remoteObjectModel} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This doesn't work. `IAppProps` has an error:

> message: 'Cannot find name 'RemoteObjectModel'.'

Also, I'm not sure if my question title properly reflects the problem (please update if it doesn't!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `RemoteObjectModel` is defined as a class, you indeed can't have nested class `Contact` defined within it.

However, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) feature of typescript - you can declare namespace `RemoteObjectModel` alongside with a class (or interface) of the same name, and declare class `Contact` within that namespace (don't forget to `export` it otherwise it will not be visible outside of the namespace).

Then, roughly speaking, whenever typescript sees `RemoteObjectModel` alone, it will refer to the class, and whenever it sees `RemoteObjectModel.something` then it will refer to the namespace.

Something like this:

```
class RemoteObjectModel {
    someProperty: string;
    constructor() {
        this.someProperty = 'someValue';
    }
}

namespace RemoteObjectModel {

    export class Contact {
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
        Phone: string;

        constructor(values: ContactProperties) {
            Object.assign(this, values);
        }
    }
}

interface ContactProperties {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Phone: string;
}

var ct = new RemoteObjectModel.Contact({
    FirstName: "Aldo",
    LastName: "Michaels",
    Phone: "(415) 555-1212"
});
```

Also, you can have [constructor signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes) defined in `RemoveObjectModel` class that allows you to call `new remoteObjectModel.Contact()` as if `Contact` is defined on the instance too:

```
class RemoteObjectModel {
    someProperty: string;
    Contact: {new(p: ContactProperties): RemoteObjectModel.Contact}
}

namespace RemoteObjectModel {

    export class Contact {
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
        Phone: string;

        constructor(values: ContactProperties) {
            Object.assign(this, values);
        }
    }
}

interface ContactProperties {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Phone: string;
}

const remoteObjectModel = new RemoteObjectModel();

var c2 = new remoteObjectModel.Contact({
    FirstName: "Aldo",
    LastName: "Michaels",
    Phone: "(415) 555-1212"
});
```

Alternatively, you can declare instance property `Contact` which is typed as 'static part' of Contact class (and can be used as constructor), using `typeof Contact`:

```
class RemoteObjectModel {
    someProperty: string;
    Contact: typeof RemoteObjectModel.Contact
    constructor() {
        this.Contact = RemoteObjectModel.Contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this works... the problems is that remoteObjectModel is passed as an *instance* and they call methods like `let acc = new remoteObjectModel.Account()`

Comment: for example, if I try that with my above code I get: 
`message: 'Property 'Contact' does not exist on type 'RemoteObjectModel'` when I call  `new this.props.remoteObjectModel.Contact()`

Comment: This could be expressed with so-called constructor signatures (interfaces that have member function named `new`), I updated the answer

Comment: wow.. I can't say it's elegant but it compiles!  Kinda of boilerplate to stub these out for every object I'm using... Maybe I could leverage generics somehow